# How can avoid to open the apps that I was using on my last session when I start the Mac?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, shutdown, catalina

Since I update my Mac to Catalina version, every time that I will start it, it opens the apps that I was using last time before to shutdown it.
On Mojave version Mac asks me if I prefer to launch the apps on next session, but Catalina didn't ask me and it opens always the apps.
Do you know how can I configure the mac to not open them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe ticking this option can help (System Preferences -> General):

[image]

Comment: Im affraid I've had enable that option, and didn't work for me :(

Comment: Have also look at the login items. From Apple support document: "Login Items always open" (https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204005)